# Sending an email when an application crashes?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, crash, notifications

I've got a big piece of scientific equipment which is hooked up to, and controlled by software running on a Windows PC. Unfortunately the software, provided by the manufacturer, crashes occasionally when nobody is there to watch it. We'd really like a piece of software which could watch the application, and when it crashes, send out an email right away. Is there anything out there like that?

EDIT: we want to monitor the application, which is a normal piece of Windows software, running on the PC. The mention of the equipment was just sort of background to explain why we cared.

Comment: Do you have a mail server on the domain?

Comment: Yup, I've got a mail server I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-get-notified-via-email-when-an-application-crashes/

http://www.jockersoft.com/english/appmonitor_index.php

It can also restart your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use some logic here..

Basically.. You need to find some sort of process/thread/task (anything really) that is always running but then freezes/stops responding that sort of thing..

For example, to monitor a specific website's uptime and downtime the specific process/thread/task is the ability to respond to TCP requests on port 80 so when they no longer respond the website is deemed down.

Without having specifics on the equipment I can really only give you a high level overview like that.

Comment: Sorry I was perhaps a little unclear, the application is just a normal piece of Windows software running on the PC. When it crashes, it really crashes, and isn't in the process list anymore.